# ¿Que significa esta expresion de Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Aun no entiendo que es esto, como se llaman, y donde hallar documentación.

```
public MyClass this[int number, params object[] arguments]
{
    get
    {
        if (number < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        //Do something
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

Podria porfavor alguien explicarme u.u

Comment: ¿Que parte del codigo no entiendes?

Comment: [Indizadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

Answer (score 3):

En realidad no es algo de .net core sino del lenguaje c# en general. Es una propiedad indizadora, es similar a una propiedad solo que se accede con [] y con los parámetros que establezcas.

Una propiedad indizadora, generalmente se utiliza cuando tu clase maneja elementos que requieren acceso a enumerables, por ejemplo, si dentro de tu clase manejas una lista o array, y no la quieres exponer como pública, puedes crear una propiedad indizadora, con la que el usuario que utilice tu clase pueda acceder a los elementos de ese enumerable de forma encapsulada.

En el ejemplo que pusiste, la forma de utilizarlo sería:

```
var myclassejemplo = objeto[0, param1, param2];
```

En este caso, objecto sería una variable de tipo de la clase que implementa el indizador, el 0 después del [ es el primer parámetro del indizador (después del this[), y param1, param2 (pueden ser mas), son el segundo parámetro del indizador.